# Installing Plex media server unofficial appstore?

Tags: plex

Looking to install the unofficial appstore from Plex to add some oher channels.  I just installed ubuntu 14.04 lts. I've been trying so many things.  I got the zip to download into the plexmediaserver plugin folder but when I try to install/unzip the package it says permission denied.  I tried it with sudo but it never went through.

Does anyone have anything that worked for them?

edit:

My install method.  I downloaded the ubuntu package from Plex website https://plex.tv/

I then went into the terminal and did the usual sudo get-apt and plex installed on my system.  I added the usual channels from Plex site to my server and now I have them on my TV(through a Roku 3).  I had windows 7 and had the plex server on that.  There is a specific channel called the unofficial Appstore.  This is where there are more channels, ie. reddit full movies channel, adult movies channel, etc. just extras that Pplex does not consider official. Now in order to get the channel on Windows & I just downloaded the zip file and windows did the rest.  For Ubuntu I was reading to do it I had to download, save to plex plugins file, unzip, change ownership and it shoudl be complete.  I was about to get the "master.zip" downloaded ffrom github.com/mikedm139/UnSupportedAppstore.bundle into my plex plug in folder.  I opened a terminal and tried the commands I found online at http://www.reddit.com/r/PleX/comments/1utl0a/plex_plugins_in_ubuntu_1204/ I got it to unzip as in it looked like it was loading in the termial but after that it keeps saying no permission even when I use sudo.

Comment: what you trying to install ok, but you forgot to mention how you trying to install ?

Answer (score 3):

I got it to work here are my steps for anyone else looking for an answer.

downloaded plex for ubuntu on the plex website.

installed via software manager

downloaded unsupported appstore on github. It was a zipfile.

I ran command

```
sudo chown username:username /var/lib/plexmediaserver/Library/"Application Support"/"Plex Media Server"/Plug-ins
```

I extracted the zip file there in the plugin folder.

Then you have to  change the name of the unsupportedappstore.master-bundle to unsupportedappstore.bundle

run command:

```
sudo mv /var/lib/plexmediaserver/Library/"Application Support"/"Plex Media Server"/Plug-ins/unsupportedappstore.master-bundle /var/lib/plexmediaserver/Library/"Application Support"/"Plex Media Server"/Plug-ins/unsupportedappstore.bundle
```

That will rename the appstore plugin.

change back the permission of plug in folder

```
sudo chown -R plex:plex /var/lib/plexmediaserver/Library/"Application Support"/"Plex Media Server"/Plug-ins/
```

lastly restart plex

```
sudo service plexmediaserver restart
```